# CMake negative lookahead (RegExp support)

Tags: regex, if-statement, cmake

Is there any way to use `(?!...)` (the negative-lookahead pattern), and somehow check result in condition?

**Or, is there any cross-platform way of running RegEx externally?**
(as my reasearch shows, CMake may never extend their RegExp support)

#### Example:

I am using CMake version `3.20.5` (current latest stable).

Example of what I tried is below:

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "^arm(?!(64))")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Got this far!!")
endif()
```

And for now, I worked it around like:

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "^arm" AND NOT CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "^arm64")
   # ...
endif()
```

#### Error log:

```
/my-project/CMakeLists.txt:60: error: given arguments: "CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR" "MATCHES" "^arm(?!(64))" Regular expression "^arm(?!(64))" cannot compile
```

#### My research:

I found the report "[CMake Regex does not support lookahead regular expressions](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/15961)" on issue-tracker
(which is clone of [original report](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15961)).

With original explanation:

> Yeah, that isn't supported.
> Adding support would likely mean rewriting the regex engine
> (which is old, global variable-driven C code).

Comment: "and maybe they don't even intend ..." - Just look into "Status": it is `Closed`. The developers don't intend to add such functionality. So, it is not clear what do you want from us (by asking your question). You don't want us to add this functionality, do you? "Or, is there any cross-platform way of running RegEx externally?" - Probably, you could find some regex tools in the net, which works on several platforms. But asking for a such tool seems to be "software recommendation", which is **off-topic** on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "It seems, CMake developers are damn lazy" -- that is not at all respectful. They have a different set of priorities than you and extended regex are not exactly an essential component of a build system. Moreover, it's _not true_. They make how many releases a year with how many new features and fixes for old bugs and mistakes?

Comment: Okay, but you saved my time as you already edited ;-) Hmm... CMake is supported by Android-Studio but not by Xcode or Visual-Studio, so, maybe it's time someone develops another Build-System which executes Java at last (or JavaScript without Browser-API of course). Would Java language allow that or would one get sued like Google was (because of Android).

Comment: CMake is supported by Visual Studio natively and can generate projects for Xcode. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-160 and https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Xcode.html

Comment: IANAL so I can't authoritatively comment on the last question. That said, I seriously doubt that simply writing a new build system in Java would invite legal problems. I would sooner contribute to improving Gradle or Maven or Ant or SBT or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the maintainer Ben Boeckel himself says in the issue you linked, the lack of support for lookahead is

> unlikely to change; would require a new regular expression engine and likely a source of many regressions.

So... no, there [isn't support for that now](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-specification) and there won't be in the future.

---

On the other hand, what you want to do can be expressed logically as:

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "^arm64")
  # Do something arm64-specific
elseif (CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "^arm")
  # We didn't take the arm64 branch, so not arm64
endif ()
```

So I don't think you *need* regex here. If you repeat these tests often, you can `set` a variable that records the result like `set(IS_ARM64 1)` and `set(IS_ARM32 1)` inside those branches.

I would argue this is significantly *cleaner* than a negative lookahead, in any language.

If you need to do some more serious regex processing you can write external Python or Perl scripts and then use [`find_package(Python 3)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html) or [`find_package(Perl)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPerl.html) to set variables `Python_EXECUTABLE` or `PERL_EXECUTABLE` with the path to the interpreter. Then you can run your script at configure time with [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) or at build time with [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html).

Comment: You mean `Python_EXECUTABLE` is automatically set by `find_package(Python 3)` call?

Comment: @Top-Master Yes. See the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html